# Flutter: How to make dropdownbutton resize according to what was selected

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to make a dropdown button resize its width according to either what item was selected in the dropdown or the width of the "hint" text. How can I do this I'm totally lost. The dropdown button is being placed inside of a ListView that is horizontally scrollable.

```
class FilterDropdown extends StatelessWidget {
  final Text? hint;
  final String? value;
  final List<DropdownMenuItem<String>>? items;
  final Function(String?)? onChanged;
  final Key? key;
  final IconData? iconData;

  FilterDropdown(
      {this.key,
      this.hint,
      this.value,
      this.items,
      this.onChanged,
      this.iconData});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0),
          color: const Color(0xff161F25),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(21, 0, 21, 0),
          child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
              child: DropdownButton<String>(
            selectedItemBuilder: (BuildContext context) {
              return items!.map<Widget>((DropdownMenuItem<String> item) {
                Text innerWidget = item.child as Text;
                return Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text(
                      innerWidget.data!,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                    )
                    // style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                    );
              }).toList();
            },
            style: const TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 16,
            ),
            key: key,
            hint: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: hint,
            ),
            value: value,
            icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down),
            items: items,
            onChanged: onChanged,
          )),
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: To clarify I want the button to resize dynamically to fit whatever it's displaying. So if I choose a drop down item that is "acb123" it will resize to closely fit that size. If I change my selection to "mississippi" it will increase in width to fit that tightly. I don't want it to have fixed size or just take the size of the largest item in the dropdown list which is the behavior I have currently. It should expand and shrink.

Answer (score 0):

```
Expanded(
    child: new Column(
    children: <Widget>[
        new DropdownButton(
            items: [
                new DropdownMenuItem(child: new Text("Abc")),
                new DropdownMenuItem(child: new Text("Xyz")),
            ],
            hint: new Text("Select City"),
            onChanged: null
          )
       ]
    ),
    flex: 1,
)
```

Use Column

Comment: In my scaffold the body is a column and one of the children of the column is a container with a child that is ListView that scrolls horizontally. I'm placing several of these dropdowns into the ListView. The container height is set to 100 but no width is set and so the list view basically has infinite scroll width. I can't put an expanded in as once of its children because that would cause a bounding issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like this:

```
Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, right: 3, top: 0, bottom: 0),
          child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            child: DropdownButton(
              icon: widget.icon,
              isExpanded: true,
              onChanged: (value) {},
              value: 0,
              items:
                    new DropdownMenuItem(child: new Text("1")),
                    new DropdownMenuItem(child: new Text("2")),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Comment: This just made it as wide as the screen

Comment: sorry my mistake